# Can't acces API from Internet Explorer

Tags: api, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8

I am developing a Vine client for Windows Phone 8 but I'm having trouble accessing their API's from desktop or mobile Internet Explorer.

When, for example, I go to "https://api.vineapp.com/timelines/graph" in Google Chrome I get a response:

```
"{"code": 100, "data": "", "success": false, "error": "You must be logged in to perform this action."}"
```

but when I do the same from the desktop Internet Explorer I get `"400: bad request"`.

I get the same error on IE on WP8 and my Lumia 920.

Anyone know the cause and a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imo, that's actually a "bug" or rather unexpected behaviour in non-IE browsers. The error code is the same as the server replies with a `400 BAD REQUEST` error.

If you access this via any real API, the response will be the same from all browsers; it's only an understandable decision by Microsofts to not show strange error messages (`Content-Type: application/json`) to end users.

Comment: So you are saying the server does give a response, but IE doesn't show a (Content-Type: application/json) response?

Comment: Yes, that's basically the gist of it :)

Comment: If you open the developer tools (F12) in IE and go to the network tab, you can inspect the request and response headers and body.